# TypeScript React Component - Validating Table Data Against Dynamic Headings

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm developing a custom React table component with TypeScript, and I need to ensure the data passed as props is correctly formatted. The component accepts two props:

- `tableHeadings`: An array of objects, where each object has an `id (string)` and a `title (string)`.
- `tableData`: An array of objects representing the rows of the table. Each object should have keys corresponding to the `id` values from `tableHeadings`.

Here's an example of the data for tableHeadings and tableData:

```
const tableHeadings = [
    {
        id: 'name',
        title: 'Name',
    },
    {
        id: 'job',
        title: 'Job',
    },
    {
        id: 'location',
        title: 'Color',
    },
    {
        id: 'country',
        title: 'Us',
    },
];

const tableData = [
    {
        name: 'Cy Ganderton',
        job: 'Quality Control Specialist',
        location: 'Canada',
        country: 'USA',
    },
    {
        name: 'Hart Hagerty',
        job: 'Desktop Support Technician',
        location: 'United States',
        country: 'USA',
    }
];
```

The component is used like this:

```
<Table tableHeadings={tableHeadings} tableData={tableData} />
```

The goal is to validate that the `tableData` prop's structure matches the `tableHeadings` prop. Specifically, each object in `tableData` should have keys that match the `id` values of the objects in `tableHeadings`.

below image shows relationship between the `id` fields of `tableHeadings` and the keys of `tableData` objects.

[image]

To define the component and its types in TypeScript, I wrote the following code:

```
// inside Table component 
type TableHeadingType = {
    id: string;
    title: string
};

type TableDataType<K extends TableHeadingType[]> = {
    [Key in K[number]['id']]: string;
}; 


type TableProps<T extends TableHeadingType> = {
    tableData: TableDataType<T[]>[];
    tableHeadings:T[]
};

export const Table = <T extends TableHeadingType>({ tableHeadings, tableData }: TableProps<T>) => {
    const headers = tableHeadings.map((column, index) => {
        return (
            <th key={`headCell-${index}`} className={''}>
                {column.title}
            </th>
        );
    });

    const rows = !tableData?.length ? (
        <tr>
            <td colSpan={tableHeadings.length} className='text-center'>
                No data
            </td>
        </tr>
    ) : (
        tableData?.map((row, index) => {
            return (
                <tr key={`row-${index}`}>
                    {tableHeadings.map((column, index2) => {
                        const value = row[column.id as keyof typeof row] as string;
                        return <td key={`cell-${index2}`}>{value}</td>;
                    })}
                </tr>
            );
        })
    );

    return (
        <>
            <table className='content-table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>{headers}</tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
            </table>
        </>
    );
};
```

However, the validation of `tableData` according to `tableHeadings` is not working and also producing no compile time or run time errors

How can I solve this?

Here is the link to the code playground for reference: https://playcode.io/1812427

If you could assist me in resolving the validation issue within my TypeScript React component, that would be very helpful.

Comment: "However, the validation of tableData according to tableHeadings is not working." What *exactly* does that mean? That's a decent amount of code, which seems to be producing no compile time or run time errors. So what specifically about this code not doing what you want? Please [edit] your question and add more detail about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `id` field type from `string` to `enum`, and than use this `enum` as the `key` at a `Record` for `tableData`

```
enum HeadingIDEnum {
 name = 'name',
 job = 'job'
 ...
}

type TableHeadingType = {
    id: HeadingIDEnum;
    title: string
};

type TableDataType = Record<HeadingIDEnum, string>[]
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

(
I used string enum as I found it more convient on your use case, as well you might use

```
const tableHeadings = [
    {
        id: HeadingIDEnum.name,
        title: 'Name',
    }
    ...
]
```

as it will on runtime turn into key-string object. but defiantly you can also use `keyof typeof` on a numeric one
)